# fix preceding forward slash in php

Tags: php

I am trying to create a local copy of a website by installing the same XAMPP version and downloading the files and mysql.

On the web server the files are saved at `http://www.website.com/html` but it is accessible through website.com

I made my own in this directory `http://localhost/website.com/html`

I am having trouble with the script because all the css and javascript have a preceding "/"

```
src="/js/prototype.js"
```

I cant explain it very good but this is a sample problem

The script originally have this

```
<link href="/_design/_master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

That doesn't work on my local install but works on the online version. But if I remove the first / on my local install it works.

```
<link href="_design/_master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

This link also works on the online version

```
<a id="logout" href="/logout.php">logout</a>
```

But on my local version it links to only `http://localhost/logout.php` but it is supposed to be linking to `http://localhost/website.com/html/logout.php`

When I remove the first / it works how ever there are so many of them and I might miss some.

Is there a setting for php for fixing this? Or did I put it on the wrong directory? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: but if it was working previously, it should be working now even. Have you channged the folder structure ?

Comment: he didn't said that is worked previously...

Comment: so the original site was anchored in doc root, this site is in a subdirectory? do you control the doc root, can you just create a symlink over?   can you put it in a vhost to put it in the docroot, other option is get familiar with your editors global find and replace tools, or something like sed if you are on a *nix system. and replace them all.

Comment: `/js/...` as an absolute path suggest that it is expected to be put on the toplevel and not into some subfolder. is it possible to arrange this in the new installation?

Comment: Do you run copy of site from subdirectory? Than it may point to the root of your web-server. You may create subdomain for localhost for your copy of the site (in Apache)/

Comment: I have updated the post I hope that can make things a bit clearer.

Comment: Ah that is the problem. When you have / as first character it assumes you are starting from the root directory, but on your local machine you don't keep it in the root directory. But if you remove the slash / it should work on both your computer and on the real website.

Answer (score 1):

Ah that is the problem. When you have / as first character it assumes you are starting from the root directory, but on your local machine you don't keep it in the root directory. But if you remove the slash / it should work on both your computer and on the real website.

first wrote: (

```
substr($string, 1)
```

That function will return the string without the first character, in your case a slash

Edit: It should have been `$string`, I forgot variables in php have `$`

)

Comment: Actually there are a lot of them and I'm not sure how many are there. Does it mean I have to edit each and everyone? or is there any setting on PHP that I can do?

Comment: No, you have to change the links manually if you entered them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Use absolute paths. Define a constant that holds the base url.

```
define('BASE_URL', 'http://mysite.com/');
```

and in includes use

```
$src = BASE_URL.'/js/prototype.js'
```

you can also check with preg_match if it has / at the begining and use substr() to substract it or use `preg_replace()`

```
$src = preg_replace('#^\/$#m', '', $src);
```